# I am not able to run the migrate command

Tags: mysql, connection, laravel-9, migrate

every time I try the migrate command in laravel it does not do it and returns this error :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La1w2.png)

my file .env:
[Env File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9FMN.png)

my file database.php:
[Database.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfltm.png)

could you help me with this?

I already created the myapp database in phpmyadmin but I can't migrate

Comment: Post the output you get here. The links to images aren’t useful

Comment: From the error, I can see, your application isn't able to connect to the database. Make sure your database is running.  You need to turn it on. If you're using Xampp, open Xampp control panel and check status.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to Code, Data or Error Messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: I think you haven't started your localhost connection yet

Comment: yes I started, I can even access my localhost through my browser

Comment: some additional information, my operating system is win 10, however, I am in the wsl2 terminal.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan optimize` after changing env file?